# This meth for a small child

Tags: meaning-in-context, pronunciation, listening

I heard [[33:54-33:56] part of this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/H0bA72fjHMQ?t=2034) as follows;

> This meth for a small child.

Did I hear it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course not. The cameraman is telling the streamer that it's possible he's about to break the Jackrabbit Trading Post's signature jackrabbit:

> It's meant for a small child.
>
> /ɪtsmɛntfɔrəsmɑl.tʃaɪəld/

You could also grok the general idea from context if you had the captions on and noticed that the response isn't "WTH are you talking about?" but instead "It looks like it's about built for you."

(If this was just a mistake from learning about the American Southwest primarily through episodes of *[Breaking Bad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breaking_Bad)*, be aware that it highly dramatizes the meth situation. It's not unknown but it's [not the most common drug](https://www.verywellmind.com/rates-of-illicit-drug-abuse-in-the-us-67027) either.)

Comment: Thank you very much.